# What does this icon mean in the UbuntuOne sign up screen?

Tags: ubuntu-one, single-sign-on

I'm trying to create a new UbuntuOne account, and getting this:
[image]

The email addresses are the same in both fields, and the password meets the criteria set. What exactly do the triangle icons mean? There's no alt text when I mouse over them, so I have no idea what it thinks is wrong with the new account setup information I'm providing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry it isn't working for you. You *should* have an “on hover” text for those alert icons; in fact, I can see them right now. However, the only thing I can think of that would produce the alert in your case is that you *already* have an SSO account with that email address. Try logging in rather than creating a new account.

Comment: I've never set up an account before, so I'm not sure how I would get an account set up with that address. However, I just tried with a different account and it went through, so apparently there's an account somewhere with my other address.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~esthermstrom-gmail seems to be you (it might have been created automatically for upstream bug tracking reasons). You can use https://login.ubuntu.com/+forgot_password if you don't have or remember the password.